# Freeze pane GridView ASP.PANE Horizontal and Vertical

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, gridview

I would like to create a freeze pane like this example image from a table.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thS7a.png)

I would like the first row and column to be dropped with another color where it says "column 1", "column 2", "column3" ... and " Row 1 "," row 2 "," row 3 "... these lines when moving any scroll bar of my grind view these lines would be frozen and always visible to the user

[Dynamically freeze ASP.Net Gridview header using JavaScript](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Dynamically-freeze-ASP.Net-Gridview-header-using-JavaScript.aspx)

This link shows how to freeze header but I would also like to do on the horizontal scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

you can use http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/ plugin.

Freeze column and fixed header in Table or GridView